# The $(\infty, 1)$-category of all topological spaces, including the bad ones

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, ct.category-theory, higher-category-theory, shape-theory

[Edit: Corrected some false claims and modified questions accordingly.]

Let $\mathcal{S}$ be the cocomplete $(\infty, 1)$-category generated by a point.
This is conventionally known as the $(\infty, 1)$-category of spaces, but for the purposes of this question it is probably best to avoid that terminology.
A lot is known about $\mathcal{S}$, but my question is about a different $(\infty, 1)$-category – the one you would get if one naïvely attempted to form the $(\infty, 1)$-category of topological spaces.

Let $\textbf{Top}$ be the category of *all* topological spaces.
I mean to include the bad ones – topological spaces not locally contractible, topological spaces not having the homotopy type of a CW-complex, non-discrete totally disconnected spaces, non-$T_0$ spaces, you name it.
As is well known, $\textbf{Top}$ is *not* cartesian closed, but this is no obstruction to getting a very good simplicial enrichment:

1. Given topological spaces $X$ and $Y$, we have a natural simplicial set $\textrm{Map} (X, Y)$ where the $n$-simplices are the continuous maps $X \times \left| \Delta^n \right| \to Y$.
   From this definition it is immediate that $\textrm{Map} (X, -) : \textbf{Top} \to \textbf{sSet}$ preserves limits and therefore has a left adjoint, which I write as $X \odot {-} : \textbf{sSet} \to \textbf{Top}$.
2. Since $\left| \Delta^n \right|$ is compact Hausdorff, it is exponentiable a fortiori, so $\textrm{Map} (X, Y)_n$ is equivalently the set of continuous maps $X \to Y^{\left| \Delta^n \right|}$.
   Hence $\textrm{Map} (-, Y) : \textbf{Top}^\textrm{op} \to \textbf{sSet}$ also preserves limits and has a left adjoint, which I write as ${-} \pitchfork Y : \textbf{sSet} \to \textbf{Top}^\textrm{op}$.

   (This probably surprises some people, since $\left| K \right|$ is not necessarily exponentiable for an infinite simplicial set $K$.
   The short answer is that $X \odot K$ is not necessarily the same as $X \times \left| K \right|$, and $K \pitchfork Y$ is not necessarily the same as $Y^{\left| K \right|}$.
   Rather, $X \odot K = \int^n X \times \left| \Delta^n \right| \times K_n$ and $K \pitchfork Y = \int_n Y^{\left| \Delta^n \right| \times K_n}$.
   When $X$ (!!) is exponentiable then $X \odot K \cong X \times \left| K \right|$.)
3. There is an evident simplicial composition map $\textrm{Map} (Y, Z) \times \textrm{Map} (X, Y) \to \textrm{Map} (X, Z)$: given $g : Y \times \left| \Delta^n \right| \to Z$ and $f : X \times \left| \Delta^n \right| \to Y$, define $g \circ_n f$ to be the composite
   $$\require{AMScd}
   \begin{CD}
   X \times \left| \Delta^n \right| 
   @>{\textrm{id}_X \times \delta_{\left| \Delta^n \right|}}>>
   X \times \left| \Delta^n \right| \times \left| \Delta^n \right|
   @>{f \times \textrm{id}_{\left| \Delta^n \right|}}>> Y \times \left| \Delta^n \right| @>{g}>> Z
   \end{CD}$$
   where $\delta_{\left| \Delta^n \right|} : \left| \Delta^n \right| \to \left| \Delta^n \right| \times \left| \Delta^n \right|$ is the diagonal embedding.

   (Basically we are exploiting the fact that every object – so $\left| \Delta^n \right|$ in particular – in a cartesian monoidal category has a unique comonoid structure.
   You can do this kind of thing whenever you have a comonoid in a monoidal category.)
4. We get an $\textbf{sSet}$-enrichment of $\textbf{Top}$.
   I have convinced myself that it is tensored and cotensored (but watch [this other question](https://mathoverflow.net/q/415573/11640)).

   (If we restrict to a complete and cocomplete cartesian closed subcategory of $\textbf{Top}$ containing the standard simplices and their finitary products, then there is definitely no problem, and the subtlety about $\odot$ and $\pitchfork$ also goes away.)
5. In fact, $\textrm{Map} (X, Y)$ is a Kan complex for all $X$ and $Y$: indeed, the natural map
   $$\textrm{Hom}_\textbf{sSet} (\Delta^n, \textrm{Map} (X, Y)) \to \textrm{Hom}_\textbf{sSet} (\Lambda^n_k, \textrm{Map} (X, Y))$$
   is a split surjection, because it can be naturally identified with the natural map
   $$\textrm{Hom}_\textbf{Top} (X, Y^{\left| \Delta^n \right|}) \to \textrm{Hom}_\textbf{Top} (X, Y^{\left| \Lambda^n_k \right|})$$
   induced by the inclusion $\left| \Lambda^n_k \right| \to \left| \Delta^n \right|$, which has a (non-canonical) retraction.

Thus, we have a complete and cocomplete $(\infty, 1)$-category $\mathcal{T}$ in the style of 1970–80s homotopy theory – this doesn't require $\textbf{Top}$ to have arbitrary simplicially enriched limits and colimits, only certain special ones with homotopical meaning – and if you insist, we can apply the homotopy coherent nerve functor to get a quasicategory, or take the nerve to get a Segal space, or whatever you please.

**Observation 1.**
Two continuous maps $X \to Y$, considered as vertices of $\textrm{Map} (X, Y)$, are in the same connected component if and only if they are homotopic in the classical sense.
In fact, an edge of $\textrm{Map} (X, Y)$ is literally a homotopy between continuous maps $X \to Y$ in the classical sense.
So the homotopy category of $\mathcal{T}$ is the *classical* homotopy category, which we know to strictly contain the homotopy category of $\mathcal{S}$: we can model $\mathcal{S}$ as the full (simplicially enriched) subcategory $\textbf{CW} \subset \textbf{Top}$ consisting of the CW-complexes, and we know that there are topological spaces not homotopy equivalent to any CW-complex.

**Question 1.**
If I understand correctly, Strøm showed that there is a model structure on $\textbf{Top}$ where the "weak equivalences" are the classical homotopy equivalences.
Thus, by general theory, we can construct a complete and complete $(\infty, 1)$-category by localising the ordinary 1-category $\textbf{Top}$ with respect to homotopy equivalences.
Does $\mathcal{T}$, as I defined it above, coincide with what general theory gives us?

**Observation 2.**
$\mathcal{S}$ is a coreflective localisation of $\mathcal{T}$.
This would be a consequence of general theory (because the mixed model structure is a right Bousfield localisation of the Hurewicz model structure) if the answer to question 1 is yes, but I think the usual construction of the Quillen model structure already contains a direct proof of this fact.

**Question 2.**
Does the embedding $\mathcal{S} \to \mathcal{T}$ have any limit preservation properties?
Are finite products preserved?
(I think finite products are preserved if we construct $\mathcal{T}$ using a convenient category of topological spaces instead.
This must have something to do with whether geometric realisation preserves finite products.)

**Observation 3.**
The functor ${-} \times T : \textbf{Top} \to \textbf{Top}$ very nearly preserves all colimits: in fact, it preserves all colimits at the level of point sets, so the only thing that can go wrong is the topology on the colimit.
If it preserved all colimits it would automatically have a right adjoint, making $T$ an exponentiable space.
Since ${-} \times T$ preserves coproducts, the failure of $\textbf{Top}$ to be cartesian closed is down to the failure of ${-} \times T$ to preserve quotient maps (= regular/strong/extremal epimorphisms) when $T$ is not a nice topological space.
But I think the situation is much better for homotopy colimits: ${-} \times T$ preserves subspace inclusions (= regular/strong/extremal monomorphisms), hence it preserves pushouts of subspace inclusions as well as directed colimits of subspace inclusions, and I believe this implies ${-} \times T$ preserves all homotopy colimits.

**Question 3.**
Does ${-} \times T$ have a homotopy right adjoint?
In other words, is $\mathcal{T}$ a cartesian closed $(\infty, 1)$-category?
In $\textbf{Top}$ the special adjoint functor theorem is available and implies $\textbf{Top}$ is a total category, but it is not clear to me whether $\mathcal{T}$ is similarly blessed.
(My understanding is that there is no analogue of the SAFT in $(\infty, 1)$-category theory.)

**Observation 4.**
$\textbf{Top}$ fails to be a locally presentable category for two reasons:

- $\textbf{Top}$ does not have a small dense generating set of objects, i.e. there is no small full subcategory $\mathbf{C}$ such that the Yoneda representation $\textbf{Top} \to [\mathbf{C}^\textrm{op}, \textbf{Set}]$ is fully faithful.
- There are objects in $\textbf{Top}$ "without rank", i.e. there is a topological space $X$ such that $\textrm{Hom}_\textbf{Top} (X, {-}) : \textbf{Top} \to \textbf{Set}$ does not preserve $\lambda$-filtered colimits for any $\lambda$.

**Question 4.**
I recall hearing that $\mathcal{T}$ is not a locally presentable $(\infty, 1)$-category.
Why not?
Is there still no small dense generating set of objects?
(This seems likely to me.)
Are there still objects "without rank"?
(I have no intuition about this, even for $\textbf{Top}$.)

I imagine some of these questions have well-known answers, but it would be nice to a definitive resource for novices confused/curious about the difference between $\mathcal{S}$ and $\mathcal{T}$.

Comment: The answer to question 1 should be yes assuming the stom model structure is simplicial (which I think is true and should be easy to check anyway) simply because every space is bifibrant in the  strom model structure and in general the infinity categorical localization of a simplicial model category is equivalent to the simplicial category of bifibrant objects.

Comment: I just noted that the nLab (http://nlab-pages.s3.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/nlab/show/Str%C3%B8m+model+structure) seems to suggest (if I understand correctly) that it is not so clear that we still know how to prove that the Strom model structure exists without restricting to k-spaces though. I don't much about the issue and maybe I'm misinterpreting what the nLab say, but that might be important for some of the question you are asking...

Comment: I also realised there are some subtleties in what I claimed. I think there's no problem if I ask about a cartesian closed category of topological spaces instead but that does make the question less well motivated...

Comment: @SimonHenry IIRC Strom's original construction worked with all topological spaces and had no issues. It was Cole's later re-proof of the theorem in the $k$-space setting which had issues. Subsequent proofs (e.g. Barthel and Riehl) have worked in $k$-spaces, are more conceptual, and also have no known issues. But there's no reason one can't work with Strom's original version in all topological spaces.

Comment: Some random thoughts: (1) Note that CW approximation shows that $\mathcal S$ is not only reflective in $\mathcal T$, but also coreflective. (2) For Question 4, note that totally disconnected spaces, viewed as objects of the simplicially-enriched category $\mathbf{Top}$, are already local with respect to $\Delta^1 \to \Delta^0$. So the 1-category of totally-disconnected spaces sits as a full reflective subcategory of $\mathcal T$. Totally disconnected spaces are not generated under colimits by any small full subcategory, so the same is true for $\mathcal T$. So $\mathcal T$ is not presentable.

Comment: @Tim Sorry, I just realised I wrote nonsense about $\mathcal{S}$ being reflective in $\mathcal{T}$. It is coreflective, for the reason you state, and morally also because the mixed model structure is a right Bousfield localisation of the Hurewicz model structure. Good point about totally disconnected spaces – $\textrm{Map} (X, Y)$ is discrete for totally disconnected $Y$, so there is a weird 1-category fully embedded in $\mathcal{T}$...

Comment: After a night's sleep I realise that tensors/cotensors with $\Delta^n$ for all $n$ + conical colimits/limits implies all tensors/cotensors, and I'm sure that we do have conical colimits and limits, so if the folklore that $\textbf{Top}$ is not tensored/cotensored is true, then we can't even have tensors/cotensors with $\Delta^n$ (for some $n$). Gah. I should ask another question about this.